# Question : Changing react state gives strange value upon addition

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, type-conversion

I want to add some value to react state.

Default state which is 21 if add 4 in it gives 25 and upon changing state via setState, let say age is set to 26 and now add 4 in it gives the result: 264 (while it should give 30).

Code looks like this:

```
    state:{
        age:21
    }

    addition(){
    var startage = this.state.age;
    var endage = this.state.age+4;

    var ageSt = parseInt(startage);
    var ageEn = parseInt(endage);
    
    console.log("start age is"+ageSt);
    console.log("end age is"+ageEn);
    ... further code
    }

    class addAge extends React.Component{
        render(){
          return(
            <div>
              <button onPress={()=>this.setState({age:26})}></button>
              ...
              <AnyCompnent onPress={this.addition}/>
            </div>

);
}
}
```

Need help, why upon changing the state it doesn't give the desired result. TIA

Answer (score 0):

Seems like age is string, so string addition is taking place.

Make sure age is a number.

Comment: You can do that with ``Number(4)`` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number)

Comment: For default state it works fine and gives correct answer. But upon changing state it gives string. How to fix this issue?

Comment: Parse your int before adding to it.

Answer (score 0):

Before adding to state convert it into Integer than add value to it works fine. E.g

```
  var startage = parseInt(this.state.age);
  var add = startage+4;
  //26+4 =30
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<button onPress={()=>this.setState({age:26})}></button>
```

should have been

```
<button onPress={()=>{this.setState({age:26})}}></button>
```